# How to receive and send data from Serial Ports in Visual Studio(Using C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am trying to set up a serial com interface that will send and receive data in the Windows Forms App with C#. I can confirm that I am sending and receiving data from the ports with the help of a virtual serial port driver app since it also shows the number of bytes sent and received. However, the text box doesn't display the received messages. There no reported errors.

[image: Image of the Form]

[image: Data Panel of the App that I am using for virtual serial port linkage]

-------The Code---------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace FormAppAuto
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonDisconnect.Enabled = false;
            buttonSend.Enabled = false;
            foreach (var serialPort in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                comboBoxSerialPorts.Items.Add(serialPort);
            }
            comboBoxSerialPorts.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboBoxSerialPorts.Text;
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort1.DataBits = 8;


            try
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show($"Seri port bağlantısı yapılamadı\n Hata : {ex.Message}", "Problem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                buttonConnect.Enabled = false;
                buttonDisconnect.Enabled = true;
                buttonSend.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void buttonDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                buttonConnect.Enabled = true;
                buttonDisconnect.Enabled = false;
                buttonSend.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Write(textBoxMyMessage.Text);
                textBoxMyMessage.Clear();
            }
        }
        public delegate void dataShow(String s);

        public void writeText(String s)
        {
            textBoxMessages.Text += s;
        }

        //private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventHandler e)
        //{
        // String dataIn = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        //textBoxMessages.Text += gelenVeri;
        //   textBoxMessages.Invoke(new dataShow(writeText), dataIn);
        // }


        private void DatareceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            String indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine("Data Received");
            Console.Write(indata);
            textBoxMessages.Text += indata;
            
        }
            
            
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you subscribe to the DataReceived event?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to coding.  What does that exactly mean?

Comment: Add `serialPort1DataReceived += DatareceivedHandler` after the Open call. Or do this in the Property window of serialPort1 on the Form

Comment: Thanks a lot your suggestion has fixed the problem.